# CakePHP How to get latest auto incremented id after saving data

Tags: cakephp

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127210/cakephp-saving-data-to-database) question as well and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979709/what-is-the-equivalent-to-getlastinsertid-in-cakephp) one as well. I am trying to implement the model described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541302/thread-messaging-system-database-schema-design) question.

What I want to do is, on the add function of message controller, create a record in thread table(this table only has 1 field which is primary key and auto increment), then take its id and insert it in the message table along with the user id which i already have, and then save it in message_read_state and thread_participant table.

This is what I am trying to do in Thread Model:

```
function saveThreadAndGetId(){
    //$data= array('Thread' => array());
    $data= array('id' => ' ');
   //Debugger::dump(print_r($data));
   $this->save($data);
   debug('id: '.$this->id);
    $threadId = $this->getInsertID();
    debug($threadId);
    $threadId = $this->getLastInsertId();
    debug($threadId);
    die();
    return $threadId;
}


$data= array('id' => ' ');
```

This line from the above function adds a row in the thread table, but i am unable to retrieve the id. Is there any way I can get the id, or am I saving it wrongly?

Initially I was doing the query thing in the message controller:

```
$this->Thread->query('INSERT INTO threads VALUES();');
```

but then i found out that lastId function doesnt work on manual queries so i reverted.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `$data` to basically an empty array with an id of `' '`.  Not sure what you were expecting out of that.  :)  Try NOT manually setting the 'id' to an empty string, and saving some data.  Then you should get the ID just fine.

Comment: what data i must save? the table only has a single id, autoincrement column, i have tried all other options, this way it savs, but doent show up the last inserted id...

Comment: I think the bigger question is, why do you have a table with a single column that stores no actual data?

Comment: I was just implementing the schema in the referred question, I have fixed it and its working now, but im wondering how to save it if somehow a table has one column/field

Comment: Try just doing $this->save(); or $this->save(array('Thread'));

Answer (score 0):

This here returns the next auto increment value.

```
/* @return int */
private function getNextThreadId() {
    $result = $this->Thread->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'threads';");
    $next = $result[0]['TABLES']['Auto_increment'];
    return $next;
}
```

Thread -> or any other name of your model

Threads -> or any other name of your db table